# Object Mapper not accessing nested Array

Tags: ios, json, swift3, objectmapper

I have the following JSON, which I am using together with ObjectMapper:

[Open Api](http://104.236.140.101/energizers/API-JSON/category-details.php)

**Response snippet**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "CategoryName": "רוגע",
      "CategoryID": "63",
      "CategoryDate": "2016-08-26 02:12:05",
      "CategoryImage": "relax.png",
      "SubCategoryArray": [
        {
          "SubCategoryName": "רוגע",
          "SubCategoryRefID": "63",
          "SubCategoryID": "86",
          "SubCategoryDate": "2016-08-28 02:57:07",
          "TextArray": [
            {
              "TextID": "32",
              "Text": "<p dir=\"rtl\"><span style=\"font-size:48px\"><strong><span dir=\"RTL\" lang=\"HE\" style=\"font-family:Arial\">פרופורציה</span></strong> . הכול הבל הבלים. חולף כהרף עין. אז לנשום.</span></p>\r\n"
            },
```

My problem is getting the data from "SubCategoryArray", and "TextArray"

I tried to do the following in my mapping:

```
import UIKit
import ObjectMapper

class APIResult: Mappable {
    var data : [dataArray]?
    required init?(map: Map){
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {

        data <- map["data"]
    }
}
class dataArray: Mappable{
    var CategoryName: String?
     var CategoryID: String?
     var CategoryDate: String?
     var CategoryImage: String?
    var SubCategoryArray: SubCategoryArray?
    required init?(map: Map){
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {

        CategoryName <- map["CategoryName"]
        CategoryID <- map["CategoryID"]
        CategoryDate <- map["CategoryDate"]
        CategoryImage <- map["CategoryImage"]
        SubCategoryArray <- map["SubCategoryArray"]
    }    
}
class SubCategoryArray: Mappable {
    var SubCategoryName: String?
    var SubCategoryRefID: String?
    var SubCategoryID: String?
    var SubCategoryDate: String?
    var TextArray: TextArray?
    required init?(map: Map){
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {

        SubCategoryName <- map["SubCategoryName"]
        SubCategoryRefID <- map["SubCategoryRefID"]
        SubCategoryID <- map["SubCategoryID"]
        SubCategoryDate <- map["SubCategoryDate"]
        TextArray <-  map["TextArray"]
    }
}
class TextArray: Mappable {
    var TextID: String?
    var Text:String?
    required init?(map: Map){
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {

        TextID <- map["TextID"]
        Text <- map["Text"]
//        SubCategoryID <- map["SubCategoryID"]
//        SubCategoryDate <- map["SubCategoryDate"]
//        TextArray <-  map["TextArray"]
    }
}
```

Please point what I am doing wrong.

Comment: as per my understanding all is good, but you are using dataArray class on top and you json response show only data , that can be the only problem.

Comment: Actually it is parsing data within data but it does not the lower levels like SubCategoryArray and TextArray

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would map this data

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class customData: Mappable {


var categoryName: String = ""
var categoryId: String = ""
var subCategoryArray: [SubCategoryArray] = []

required init?(_ map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    categoryName            <- map["data.CategoryName"]
    categoryId              <- map["data.CategoryID"]
    subCategoryArray        <- map["data.SubCategoryArray"]
}
}

class SubCategoryArray: Mappable {


var SubCategoryName: String = ""
var SubCategoryRefID: String = ""

var textArray: [TextArray] = []
required init?(_ map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    SubCategoryName         <- map["SubCategoryName"]
    SubCategoryRefID        <- map["SubCategoryRefID"]
    textArray               <- map["TextArray"]

}
}

class TextArray: Mappable {


var TextID: String = ""
var Text: String = ""

required init?(_ map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    TextID              <- map["TextID"]
    Text                <- map["Text"]
}
}
```

Let me know if you find any difficulty.